# Как не обрезать изображение, watermark?

Tags: php, watermark

Задача состоит в том что бы не обрезать края под размер 900на600,
а сжимать.
Мой код его просто обрезает но это не совсем подходит

```
public function smart_resize($file_input, $file_output, $_w, $_h, $min_w = 100, $min_h = 100) {

        $getimagesize = getimagesize($file_input);
        if (($_w==$min_w) && ($_h == $min_h)) {
            $width = $min_w;
            $height = $min_h;
        } else if (($getimagesize[0]>$_w) && ($getimagesize[1]>$_h)) {
            $width = $_w;
            $height = $_h;
        } else if (($getimagesize[0]>=$_w) && ($getimagesize[1]<$_h)) {
            $width = $_w;
            $height = ($width/($getimagesize[0]/$getimagesize[1]));
        } else if (($getimagesize[0]<$_w) && ($getimagesize[1]>$_h)) {
            $height = $_h;
            $width = ($height/($getimagesize[1]/$getimagesize[0]));
        } else {
            $height = $getimagesize[1];
            $width = $getimagesize[0];
        }

        if (($width<$min_w) || ($height<$min_h)) {
            return 'error';
        }

        $_w = $width;
        $_h = $height;

        $w_o = $_w;
        $h_o = null;

        list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);

        $types = array('jpg','gif','jpeg','png');
        $ext = $types[$type];
        if ($ext) {
            $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
            $img = $func($file_input);
        }
        if (($w_o/($w_i/$h_i))<$_h) {
            $h_o = $_h;
            $w_o = null;
        }
        if (!$h_o) {
            $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i);
        }
        if (!$w_o) {
            $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i);
        }
        $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
        imageAlphaBlending($img_o,false);
        imageSaveAlpha($img_o,true);
        imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);
        if ($h_o<$_h) {
            $_img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($_w, $_h);
            imageAlphaBlending($_img_o,false);
            imageSaveAlpha($_img_o,true);
            $src_x = (($_w/2)-($w_o/2));
            $src_y = (($_h/2)-($_h/2));
            imagecopy($_img_o, $img_o, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $_w, $_h);
            imagejpeg($_img_o, ($file_output? $file_output : null), 90);
            imagedestroy($img_o);
        } else if ($h_o>=$_h) {
            $_img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($_w, $_h);
            imageAlphaBlending($_img_o,false);
            imageSaveAlpha($_img_o,true);
            $src_x = (($w_o/2)-($_w/2));
            $src_y = (($h_o/2)-($_h/2));
            imagecopy($_img_o, $img_o, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $_w, $_h);
            imagejpeg($_img_o, ($file_output? $file_output : null), 90);
            imagedestroy($img_o);
        } else {
            imagejpeg($img_o, ($file_output? $file_output : null), 90);
            imagedestroy($img_o);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Есть еще предложения?

Answer (score 2):

Держите старую, далеко не идеальную, но зато рабочую функцию, которая будет сжимать, а не обрезать изображения:

```
// ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ РАЗМЕРОВ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ И ЗАПИСЬ НА ДИСК
// $image_path_original ... str путь к изменяемой картинке
// $max_width ............. максимальная ширина изображения
// $max_height ............ максимальная высотв изображения
// $ext ................... расширение изображения (gif или jpg)
// $image_path_save ....... путь, куда будет записано измененное изображение

function image_resize($image_path_original, $max_width, $max_height, $ext, $image_path_save)
  {     
  $max_width = intval($max_width);
  $max_height = intval($max_height);
  $size = GetImageSize($image_path_original);
  $width = $size[0];
  $height = $size[1];
  $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
  $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;
  if ( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height) )
    {
    $tn_width = $width;
    $tn_height = $height;
    }
  else if ( ($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height)
    {
    $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
    $tn_width = $max_width;
    }
  else 
    {
    $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
    $tn_height = $max_height;           
    }

  if ($ext == "gif")
    {
    $fp                        = fopen($image_path_original,"rb");
    $result                    = fread($fp,13);
    $this[m_signature]    = mb_substr($result,0,3);
    $this[m_version]        = mb_substr($result,3,3);
    $this[m_width]        = ord(mb_substr($result,6,1)) + ord(mb_substr($result,7,1)) * 256;
    $this[m_height]        = ord(mb_substr($result,8,1)) + ord(mb_substr($result,9,1)) * 256;
    $this[m_colorFlag]   = ord(mb_substr($result,10,1)) >> 7;
    $this[m_background]   = ord(mb_substr($result,11));
    if($this[m_colorFlag])
      {
      $tableSizeNeeded = ($this[m_background] + 1) * 3;
      $result = fread($fp, $tableSizeNeeded);
      $this[m_transparentRed]    = ord(mb_substr($result,$this[m_background] * 3,1));
      $this[m_transparentGreen]    = ord(mb_substr($result,$this[m_background] * 3 + 1,1));        
      $this[m_transparentBlue]    = ord(mb_substr($result,$this[m_background] * 3 + 2,1));            
      }
    fclose($fp);
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($image_path_original);
    $dst = imagecreate($tn_width, $tn_height);
    if($this[m_version] == '89a' && $this[m_colorFlag] == 1)
      {
      $transparent = imagecolorallocate($src, $this[m_transparentRed], $this[m_transparentGreen], $this[m_transparentBlue]);
      imagecolortransparent ($src, $transparent);
      }
    $transparent = imagecolorallocate($dst, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent ($dst, $transparent);
    }
  else
    {
    $src = ImageCreateFromJpeg($image_path_original);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);
    }
  imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tn_width,$tn_height,$width,$height);
  if ($ext == "gif")
    {
    imagegif($dst, $image_path_save);
    }
  else
    imagejpeg($dst, $image_path_save, 80);
  ImageDestroy($src);
  ImageDestroy($dst);   
  }
```

Comment: спасибо большое даже если вашу выбирать скажите что поменять в вашем коде что был похож на мой

Comment: К параметрам функции есть подробные комментарии, я думаю вам не составит труда просто изучить готовое решение, к тому же параметры вашей и моей функции схожи.